Invoices Id that resets when the user need it
I have a database table invoices, the table contains three fields id auto incremented, created_at and invoice_id, I want to make the invoice_id so that each day or each time the user needs to reset the invoice_id, it start from 1 again.
so the way I solved this problem is by using postgres transaction isolation, to prevent race condition when I try to read then write the new invoice_id, and made the invoice_id as unique, made so that the starting invoice_id is 1001 this way I only increment it by one when adding new invoice, and only show the last three digits in the invoice, and when I need to reset I can increase the invoice_id by 1000 and reset the three digits to start be like this 2001, in case when I need to get the last record, from what I know MAX(id) is slow when I have millions of records, so I could use a separate table that has only one record to save the last id, and increase it every time I add a new record, this way we know exactly where is the id, and do not need to use MAX(id), this would be faster.
is this the best solution, or is there something better than this, I feel like I've gone to a very complex solution, could be simpler and more efficient ?

Why are you resetting the invoice id's each day? The created_at will server to distinguish the days.

MAX(id) is really fast when id is indexed. The problem is concurrency, you must lock the table to avoid other processes reading the same max(id).

This is horrifically complicated. Why are you doing this at all? The invoice number should just always be incremented - you don't need the first digit to show what day it was on, because you have an invoice date. You're making it way too difficult. It also overly complicates things - you're showing the user three digits, so what do they do when a customer calls in and asks for help with an invoice? And if you have a four digit invoice number, what happens on day 10, when 10001 will overflow the column? If you just let it increment, you have room for 9999 invoices.

(continued) And what are the odds that you'll need 999 invoices in a day? Suppose you only have 10, which leaves you at 1010 at the end of day 1, wasting 990 invoice numbers that could have been used. If you do it properly, you'll get to use those 990 numbers.

@KenWhite let me tell more about the project, this is a cashier system, where I have multiple cashiers entering new orders, the client needs to reset the number that is showing on the receipt so that the real number of orders is never known by customers.

odds are very low that I'll need 999 invoices because the client needs to reset it before it reaches 100 or 200 because that is the main idea is to hide these real numbers, also they insist on numbers, so UUIDs or character based ids is no solution here.

Don't show the customer the invoice_id. Create a seq_id field that  is displayed on invoice and have it be an integer type with  GENERATED ALWAYS  AS IDENTITY per CREATE TABLE. Then just reset the sequence behind the IDENTITY to start at 1 every night.
